# React Native: AWS Amplify Auth.signOut() not working

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

React Native noob here, trying to implement AWS Amplify authentication flow into my project. But the `Auth.signOut()` function is not working at all. Nothing happens when I press the `logout` button.

```
const onLogOutPressed = async () => {
        //Auth.signOut();
        try {
            await Auth.signOut({ global: true });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error Logging Out', error);
        }
    }
```

My first version was purely `Auth.signOut()` as that was what the tutorial I was following did. Another guide suggested using the try method so I commented the first Auth function and added the rest.

Some help would be greatly appreciated. Do let me know if more info is required, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React Native UI from Amplify and wrapped your component with `withAuthenticator`, below code should work.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  };

  ...

    Auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.props.onStateChange(("signedOut");
    });
}
```

```
// Functional component
const App = (props) => {

  ...

    Auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.props.onStateChange("signedOut", null);
    })
}
```

If you're not using React Native UI, then you need to handle redirection yourself. `Auth.signOut()` will only clear session.